# Answer How to render the edit template in Kendo ListView

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-template, kendo-listview

Answering the following question [Kendo MVC ListView Editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702969/kendo-mvc-listview-editing)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is an answer to another question

Answer (score 0):

Kendo in MVC uses a folder with the following path View/Shared/EditorTemplates
inside this folder you must insert all the templates you call by name, example:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView<temp.Models.YourTable>(Model)
    .Name("LisView")
    .TagName("div")
    .ClientTemplateId("templateView") => here goes the template for data
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Model(m => m.Id("ID"))
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Read(read => read.Action("ActionRead", "Controller"))
    )
    .Editable(edit => edit.TemplateName("EditTmpl")) 
)
```

EditTmpl => // this template is the one that you must store in the folder that I refer above.

hope this helps.

Comment: Please post your answer on that question, and not in a new post.